# Echoing variables in PHP without calling them

Tags: php

Let's say I have something like this:

```
echo "This is a $variable";
echo "<?php echo $var; ?>";
```

How can I make it simply output:

```
This is a $variable
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

Instead of trying to parse the variables?

Comment: Please add the expected output. Your question is hard for me to understand the goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single-quotes rather than double-quotes:

```
$var = 'This is a $variable';
echo $var;
```

**Output:**

```
This is a $variable
```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes

```
echo 'This is a $variable';
echo '<?php echo $var; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single-quotes instead of double-qoutes:

```
echo '<?php echo $var; ?>';
```

If you want to show it in a web browser, use htmlentities so it's not interpreted as a html tag:

```
echo htmlentities('<?php echo $var; ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes

```
echo 'my vars = $a, $b, $c';
```

or if you need double quotes escape **$** sign with slash in front of it like:

```
echo "my vars = \$a, \$b, \$c";
```

or use **`chr(36)`** to replace $ sign (my fav :) ), or.... etc